# Making a Simple Quiz

Tags: java

I am new to java and so I wrote this code, it is meant to be a simple quiz. I want the question repeated if the user input is not valid(i.e. They give an answer like "h".)

This is my code, I don't understand why its not working. it asks the question once and the execution finishes. NOTE:This is Java IDE.

```
 do 
    {
        c.println ("Q1:   What is the TV-B-Gone");
        c.println ("A) A TV");
        c.println ("B) A Car");
        c.println ("C) A Remote");
        c.println ("D) Water");
        Q1 = c.readChar ();    
        if (Q1=='c'|| Q1=='C')
        {
           c.println("that is the right answer");
           counter++;
           break;
        }
        else if(Q1=='B'|| Q1=='b' || Q1=='a'|| Q1=='A'|| Q1=='d'|| Q1=='D')
        {
           c.println("thats incorrect");
           break;
        }
    }
    while (Q1 == 'A' || Q1 == 'a' || Q1 == 'B' || Q1 == 'b' || Q1 == 'D' || Q1 == 'd'||Q1 == 'c' || Q1 == 'C');
```

Comment: Please edit It as code

Comment: Are you pressing enter after you answer?

Comment: there is that : `c.println("thats incorrect");
               break;` you break the loop when the answer is wrong.

Comment: @njzk2 I did that cause if they answer one of the other options but it is wrong that's fine.

Answer (score 1):

In the loop control (`while (...)`), you need `!=` (does not equal) instead of `==` (equals)

Comment: When i did that the question is asked twice.

Comment: That is because the part that prints the question is inside the loop.